# How can i restrict the request from the unauthorized users (url's)?

Tags: java, spring, jsp

Here my problem is that in my spring project totally 3 Jsp pages are available.

1. home page
2. register page
3. register success full page

When i type url for the home page in a browser, i am getting home page.and inside one hyperlink is available to register data. automatically when i click on that link it will go to the register page.then after it will go to the register success full page.

So finally my problem is that when i gave home page url in browser, homepage comes and also if i give register page url it will go to the register page with out touches the home page. but actually i want to access the register page through home page.

Answer (score 0):

Use a token like JWT, set the token on access through Home page. Use a MVC Interceptor or a Filter and check that the token is present in the request before presenting the register page . If token not present redirect to home page.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security allows user's to access the url's as per authorization.
You can specify, which user has access to which url, if the user is not authorized then redirect to home page or just say access denied.

Please refer the spring security doc.it might help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create an authentication filter and specify on which methods you need to call this filter, for example, you want only an authorised user to access the downloadDoc api. Here is the sample code for this:

```
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = { "/getDocs", "/downloadDoc", "/updateStatus", "/submitApplication", "/login", "/logout",
    /*"/requestDocuments", "/sendEmailRequest"*/"/getAllApplication", "/getApplicationDetails",
    "/getAccountDetails" })

public class AuthenticationFilter implements Filter {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AuthenticationFilter.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserVerificationService userVerificationService;

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest arg0, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        logger.info("checking token in filter");
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) arg0;
        if (!request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("OPTIONS")) {
            DocVerificationRequestWrapper myRequestWrapper = new DocVerificationRequestWrapper(request);
            String body = myRequestWrapper.getBody();
            String serviceName = request.getServletPath();
            logger.info("serviceName = " + serviceName);
            Token token = null;
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(body);
                logger.info(jsonObj);
                if (jsonObj != null) {
                    JSONObject tokenObj = (JSONObject) jsonObj.get("token");
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    token = gson.fromJson(tokenObj.toString(), Token.class);

                    String clientName = request.getHeader("clientName");
                    logger.info("clientName = " + clientName);
                    if (null != token) {
                        if (userVerificationService == null) {
                            ServletContext servletContext = request.getServletContext();
                            WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext = WebApplicationContextUtils
                                    .getWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
                            userVerificationService = webApplicationContext.getBean(UserVerificationService.class);
                        }
                        ClientResponse cr = userVerificationService.verifyUser(token, clientName, serviceName);
                        String verStatus = cr != null ? cr.getStatus() : null;
                        logger.info("verStatus = " + verStatus);
                        if (verStatus != null && verStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
                            chain.doFilter(myRequestWrapper, response);
                        } else {
                            logger.error("Invalid token");
                            cr.setStatus("failure");
                            cr.setMessage("Invalid Token");
                            cr.setErrorCode("157");
                            cr.setToken(token);
                            response.getOutputStream().write(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsBytes(cr));

                            // ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendError(157, "Invalid Token");
                        }
                    } else {
                        logger.error("token missing.");
                        ClientResponse cr = new ClientResponse();
                        cr.setStatus("failure");
                        cr.setMessage("Missing Token");
                        cr.setErrorCode("158");
                        response.getOutputStream().write(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsBytes(cr));
                        // ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendError(158, "Token Missing");
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                logger.error("exception in authetication filter " + e);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```